# Migrate files from drupal 7 to drupal 8

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7, migration, drupal-8

I have Drupal 7 website and i need to upgrade it to Drupal 8 i’ve followed drupal website documentation for upgrading to drupal 8 using web browser https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrade-using-web-browser#source-site

Now both sites installed in the same server with different domains.

When i added database access all data migrated successfully else the media files because I have an error in public file directory input  i’ve tried the following directories but each one return error.

1- When I added public files directory with the website address as https://drupal7migration.mydomain.com/sites/default/files

Or

https://drupal7migration.mydomain.com/sites/default/files

the error was unable to read from public files directory. Client error 'Head  https://drupal7migration.mydomain.com/sites/default/files' resulted in a 404 not found response.

2- When I added the local file directory:   /var/www/vhosts/drupal7migration.mydomain.com/httpdocs/sites/default/files

Or

/var/www/vhosts/drupal7migration.mydomain.com/httpdocs/sites/default/files/public

Or

/var/www/vhosts/drupal7migration.mydomain.com/httpdocs/sites/default/public

the error was "unable to read from public files directory".

also the sites folder has 777 permission.

So, what’s the right public file directory that should be added to migrate both database and files successfully?

Comment: so the question is you have code and db running except /files?

Answer (score 0):

The files folder usually lives in :
/sites/yourSite/files.

Given the errors you indicated, it sounds like the “web server” doesn’t have enough permissions to the /sites/yourSite/files (read, write , and execute).

So determine the user under which your web server is running and make sure that use has enough permission.

See docs for more:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/setting-up-the-files-directory

Also, look at your web server vhost to get the actual documentRoot location. 
I don’t think what you have is correct:
 /var/www/vhosts/drupal7migration.mydomain.com/httpdocs/sites/default/files

Is probably meant to be

/var/www/vhosts/drupal7migration.mydomain.com/sites/default/files

**Normally**,
You have /

> var/www/HTML/example.com

**Point**
to your Drupal install as:

/

> yourDrupalInstall/sites/example.com

Or

> /yourDrupalInstall/sites/default

```
                                  /files
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, I just looked up on my Drupal 7 site under Configuration -> Media -> File System what my public file system path is. See screenshot below.

sites/default/files is what worked for me after looking in configuration!

**Screenshot of public files location**

[image]